# Not able to containerise .net 5.0 web API

Tags: .net, docker

I need to containerise a .net 5.0 web application which is running fine on windows IIS Server. i have written below docker file. i am able to build image with the docker file, however when i am trying to access it. i am getting error that This site can’t be reached. Please help me out here. new to docker and new to linux.

Docker File:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app   
EXPOSE 80
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS="http://*:5000"

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build

WORKDIR /src

COPY ["API/WebUI/Summit.API.csproj", "API/WebUI/"]

COPY ["Application/Summit.Application.csproj", "Application/"]

COPY ["Domain/Shared/Summit.Domain.csproj", "Domain/Shared/"]

COPY ["Domain/SqlKata.Execution/SqlKata.Execution.csproj", "Domain/SqlKata.Execution/"]

COPY ["Domain/QueryBuilder/QueryBuilder.csproj", "Domain/QueryBuilder/"]

COPY ["Infrastructure/Summit.Infrastructure.csproj", "Infrastructure/"]

RUN dotnet restore "API/WebUI/Summit.API.csproj"

COPY . .

WORKDIR "/src/API/WebUI"

RUN dotnet build "Summit.API.csproj" -c Release 

FROM build AS publish

RUN dotnet publish "Summit.API.csproj" -c Release

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0 AS runtime

WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=publish /src/API/WebUI/bin/Release/net5.0/publish .

EXPOSE 5000

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Summit.API.dll"]
```

I ma manually building image from the docker file using command docker container run -itd -p 8000:5000 imageid

post that when i am trying to access http://localhost:5000/swagger not able to access it.

Please help me out here.

Comment: I think `-p 8000:5000` publishes port 5000 in the container on port 8000 on localhost, meaning you'd need `http://localhost:8000/swagger`. I think you want `--publish` instead of `-p 8000:5000` to use the EXPOSE directive and publish port 5000 as-is.

Comment: What changes i need to do, any suggestion.

Comment: If you want to publish this on port 5000 either use `--publish` or `-p 5000:5000` on the run command instead of `-p 8000:5000`.

Comment: hi @Rup

I tried but not able to access localhost:5000/swagger/index.html

i am trying to access it from same ubuntu server where my container is running.

Comment: however when i am checking process with respect to port number i can see below

docker-pr 357104            root    4u  IPv4 2096378      0t0  TCP *:5000 (LISTEN)
docker-pr 357108            root    4u  IPv6 2096395      0t0  TCP *:5000 (LISTEN)

Comment: I'd run a bash terminal on the container then and make sure the server is running on port 5000 inside the container.

Comment: When i am running a bash terminal on the container i can see all my dll in the root folder that is /app. do i need to check for ssl certificate and all

Comment: That depends what you've got set up, but this doesn't sound like an SSL problem, at least not yet. You need to check that you can connect to `http://localhost:5000/` from inside the container, i.e. that your app is running and running on that port.

Comment: when i am trying to access the container through ip (ip of the vm on which container is running) with port number 5000 http://ip-of-container-vm:5000/swagger/index.html i am getting same error.

however, when i am manually building the app through cli, dotnet build projectnae.csproj. i am able to access it with localhost://5000. not sure what mistake i am doing

Comment: Your docker publish is probably just publishing it to localhost only so it cannot be accessed from other machines, only the machine that's hosting the docker. But I'd concentrate on fixing it on localhost first then worry about that. As above I'd still verify that the app is running inside the container first.

Comment: how to connect to localhost:5000 from inside a container

Comment: OK, can you go to /app in the container and try `dotnet Summit.API.dll`, the command you're using to start the server? I guess that's not working.

Comment: System.IO.IOException: Failed to bind to address http://127.0.0.1:5000: address already in use.
finally aborted

Comment: D'oh, I misread: I thought you said you couldn't connect, not asking how to connect. You want  `curl http://localhost:5000/` inside the container or /swagger/.

Comment: when i am doing curl inside app, it is saying command not found. i am sry but i am verry new and my answere might be frustating you. thank you for being so patient. please let me know how to fix it

Comment: Oh, I guess Microsoft use a minimal linux image that doesn't provide curl. You can probably install it if you can work out which linux distro it is, but I guess we already know that the server is running on port 5000 so maybe that's not important. I'm not sure what to suggest next then: it's running on port 5000 inside the container, it sounds like you're exposing the port properly but then it's not working. Don't know, sorry.

Comment: no problem, thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

You never use the `base` temporary image you create, so your ASPNETCORE_URLS environment variable is thrown away. That means that your app is listening on the default port 80.

Also, your app isn't running in Development mode, which means that Swagger won't be available (at least if you're using the default webapi template).

Try this Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app   
EXPOSE 5000
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS="http://*:5000"
ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["API/WebUI/Summit.API.csproj", "API/WebUI/"]
COPY ["Application/Summit.Application.csproj", "Application/"]
COPY ["Domain/Shared/Summit.Domain.csproj", "Domain/Shared/"]
COPY ["Domain/SqlKata.Execution/SqlKata.Execution.csproj", "Domain/SqlKata.Execution/"]
COPY ["Domain/QueryBuilder/QueryBuilder.csproj", "Domain/QueryBuilder/"]
COPY ["Infrastructure/Summit.Infrastructure.csproj", "Infrastructure/"]
RUN dotnet restore "API/WebUI/Summit.API.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/API/WebUI"
RUN dotnet build "Summit.API.csproj" -c Release 

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Summit.API.csproj" -c Release

FROM base AS runtime
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /src/API/WebUI/bin/Release/net5.0/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Summit.API.dll"]
```

Build and run it with

```
docker build -t myimage .
docker run -d -p 8000:5000 myimage
```

Then Swagger should be available at http://localhost:8000/swagger

If you prefer, you can remove the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT from the Dockerfile and instead pass it in on your `docker run` command. I like having it in the Dockerfile while I develop.

Edit: To test, I changed the build step in the middle of the Dockerfile so it creates a webapi app from the default template like this

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src/API/WebUI
RUN dotnet new webapi -n Summit.API -o .
WORKDIR /src
RUN dotnet restore "API/WebUI/Summit.API.csproj"
WORKDIR "/src/API/WebUI"
RUN dotnet build "Summit.API.csproj" -c Release
```

Since it doesn't work for you, then the problem probably is in your code.

Comment: no luck, tried with above dockerfile @hans

Comment: @ChandraShekhar I added a build step to the bottom of my answer that demonstrates that the Dockerfile works with a default webapi app. Since it doesn't work for you, then I think there must be an issue with your code.

Comment: but same code base is working fine on windows IIS

Comment: There can be a lot of reasons why that is. It's really hard to tell why without seeing the code.